# WPF Binding to behave OneWayToSource and OneTime

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Is it possible for a control binding to behave as `OneWayToSource` and `OneTime`?

Here is some background: I have a data grid. Each row has text cells and a `checkbox`. If the `checkbox` is selected the data from the row will be saved. Now, when user starts typing in any text cell I change the `IsChecked` property in my ViewModel so the `checkbox` gets checked. I would like this to happen only once. So, for example, if a user starts typing and decides to uncheck the `checkbox` I don't want to change it when the user will start typing value again.

Sounds for me like setting binding to both `OneWayToSource` and `OneTime` should be a solution but I know binding mode can be set only to a single value. I've been searching for some suggestions and possible workarounds to achieve similar result but with no result.

Answer (score 1):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.110).aspx):

> OneTime updates the target property only when the application starts
>   or when the DataContext undergoes a change

That means that using a combination of `OneWayToSource` and `OneTime` would not solve your issue as the 'one time'-update does not trigger the moment the property changes the first time but on application start or datacontext change.

As you bound your text cell text to some property you can control in that property if `IsChecked` should be set or not.

```
private string text_ = "";
private bool isChecked_ = false;
private bool autoSetChecked_ = true;

public bool IsChecked
{
  get
  {
    return isChecked_;
  }
  set
  {
    if (isChecked_ == value) {
      return;
    }

    // If user manually changes check state assume the user wants to keep that state
    // => Disable auto changing.
    autoSetChecked_ = false;
    isChecked_ = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
  }
}

public Text
{
  get
  {
    return text_;
  }
  set
  {
    if (text_ == value) {
      return;
    }

    text_ = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("Text");

    if (autoSetChecked_) {
      // Only set is checked if not done ever before.
      autoSetChecked_ = false;
      IsChecked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:** This requires that your `IsChecked`-Binding is TwoWay so you can change the checkbox from your viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just wonder if it's possible to achieve this result purely in XAML.

Comment: You want to have a 'OnFirstChangeAndOneWayToSource'-Binding. This might work in pure xaml but you can manually raise a change-notify from your code-behind/viewmodel for a property even if the property did not change. This would probably break the binding mode, as it does not always work but would rely on the usecase/implementation.